# How to use patch command in WinSCP?

Tags: command-line, ssh, ftp, winscp, patch

I need to apply [this patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/52589/52589.patch) to my WordPress website. It seems that to do that, I need to SSH to my hosting and use Unix command `patch < path_to_patch`. However, since I'm using a shared hosting, not VPS, I don't have SSH. Is there a way to do this in WinSCP? Or is manually changing the files the only way to do this?

Comment: You do not need to apply this patch, you can't apply it to a standard WordPress site as that patch is not for a WordPress site, and the patch changes something in the twentytwentyone theme, not in WordPress. So even if you could SSH into your server, you would not be able to apply the patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute commands on a remote server, you need a shell access. It seems that you do not have it (that's my understanding of yours *"I need to SSH to my hosting... However, I'm unable to do that right now."*)

While you can execute shell commands in WinSCP, it needs the shell access for that in any case.

So if you cannot *"SSH to your hosting"*, you cannot execute the commands, no matter what client you use.

---

Though in your specific case, you can download the files to the local machine, apply the patch, and upload the modified files back.

---

If you are applying patches frequently, you can set up a [custom command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_command) for that.